How do I append to a string in C and write that modification back to the original string?
It is my first day writing programs in C and am confused as to why this code does not work. I have programmed before in C#.
Essentially, I am trying to initialise an empty string called onesString and run the C equivalent of what onesString += "I" is in, say, C#. It is not letting me access the memory and overwrite the string. This is within the context of trying to convert an integer into a roman numeral.
Here is the code, which I have tried to piece together from tutorials online:
#include <stdio.h>

char * ToRomanNumeral(int integer) {
    if (integer > 10) {
        return "Not implemented";
    }

    int ones = integer % 10;

    char * onesString = malloc(1000);

    //makes the ones string
    if (ones == 9) {
        strcpy(onesString, "IX");
    }
    else if (ones >= 5) {
        strcpy(onesString, "V");

    }
    else if (ones == 4) {
        strcpy(onesString, "IV");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ones % 5; i++)
    {
        strcpy(onesString, strcat(onesString, "I"));
    }

    return onesString;
}

int main() {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    printf("Hello, World!");

    printf(ToRomanNumeral(1));
    return 0;
}

The issue occurs on the line strcpy(onesString, strcat(onesString, "I"));. It gives me the error Access violation reading location.
I do not understand what is wrong with this, as I have allocated a lot of space with the malloc(1000) line of code.
I have also tried instead initialising onesString as char onesString[] = "";, char * onesString = ""; but nothing seems to work.
What can I do to get the desired result?

strcat(onesString, ... returns onesString so you effectively have strcpy(onesString, onesString) which is undefined behaviour since the source and destination overlap.  Why do you think you need strcpy at all?

printf(ToRomanNumeral(1)) should be printf("%s\n", ToRomanNumeral(1)). Don't ever use the variable you're printing as the format string (unless you're creating the format string dynamically, which is more advanced than you're ready for).

It seems like you don't realize that strcat() does the in-place concatenation you want.

strcat is not a function that would allocate a new string for you in C. It concatenates the string on the same destination buffer you specified. Also, you need to be careful on buffer overflows, as strcpy and strcat do not have buffer size argument. It's more recommended to use snprintf which has a safer API against this.

And also, consider if you are building up a (long) string, it's better to use a temporary cursor-pointer and keeping that around instead of strcat: every time it is called, it has to loop through the entire string to find the end, O(n^2).

The caveat with strcat() is that the destination string needs to have a terminator, and malloc() does not ensure that there is one.  You could allocate with calloc() instead to ensure that the whole allocated space is zero-filled, or you could just write a terminator to the first byte of the space (at index 0) before first strcating to it.

asprintf will allocate as much as necessary

// MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE THE RIGHT HEADERS
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <string.h> // string manip. functions

char* onesString = malloc(1000);
// like John Bollinger mentioned, the memory needs to be zero initialized 
// (theoretically only the first character, but better to be safe than sorry)
memset(onesString, 0, 1000);
strcat(onesString, "I");

C will tolerate not having the headers included directly, but it will give you a warning. And doing it propperly is better for the compiler and the LSP. You never kwow when an obsolete feature will get deprecated.
The faster version for appending a single character in a loop would look something like that:
int end = strlen(onesString);
for (int i = 0; i < ones % 5; i++)
{
    onesString[end++] = 'I';
}

No need to seek the null terminator every time.
Just one more little thing, the loop falsely adds I to strings that actually intended for subtracting. A little change to your logic can fix that:
char * ToRomanNumeral(int integer) {
    int ones = integer % 10;

    char * onesString = malloc(16); // maximal length reachable
    if (integer > 10) {
        // always return an allocation, so you can always free it
        // mentioned by Explorer09
        strcpy(onesString, "not implemented");
        return onesString;
    }

    // makes the ones string
    if (ones == 9) {
        strcpy(onesString, "IX");
    } 
    else if (ones == 4) {
        strcpy(onesString, "IV");
    }
    else 
    { 
        if (ones >= 5) {
            strcpy(onesString, "V");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ones % 5; i++)
        {
            strcat(onesString, "I");
        }
    }
    
    return onesString;
}


"like John Bollinger mentioned, the memory needs to be zero initialized" - that's not quite what he said. He said "the destination string needs to have a terminator". Now you can zero initialize withmemset() to set all 1000 bytes zero (overkill), or simply set the first byte zero, e..g. *oneString = 0; or oneString[0]  = 0; whichever you prefer. The point being that to know where the original string ends, the nul-terminator is used. With a new uninitialized block of memory, you must place the terminator at the beginning to use strcat() to fill that new block.

Also for 0 <= integer < 4 your last code block has the same problem as the question. You may want to address that.

Don't return "Not implemented" string directly because it's a string literal in a read-only memory and it's not allocated using malloc. If the caller code later tries to call free on the buffer, that's an undefined behavior and usually it results in a crash. Return NULL or strdup("Not implemented") instead!
